# Installing dplyr in R version 3.2.1

Tags: r, rstudio

Cannot install `dplyr` in a `R 3.2.1 version`. I tried everything, I downloaded a previous version of dplyr in the laptop (0.4.2), I tried from other mirrors, but still cannot get it installed. The same with "tidyverse"

When I try it locally it says:

> - installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
>     ** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs sh: make: command not found ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/dplyr’
> - restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/dplyr’
>     Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>     ‘/Users/x/Desktop/Master/R/dplyr_0.4.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit statu

That's the local error.
The online version of installing it says

> it cannot be installed

my sessioninfo

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) locale: [1] es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/C/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8 attached base packages: [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base other attached packages: [1] remotes_2.0.4 loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] httr_1.4.0 R6_2.4.0 tools_3.2.1 RCurl_1.95-4.8 digest_0.6.10 bitops_1.0-6

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try updating the `R` version.  Also try with [versions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/versions/versions.pdf) package

Comment: Including the output of `sessionInfo()` may make it easier to confirm your setup allow others to provide help

Comment: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)

locale:
[1] es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/C/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] remotes_2.0.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.4.0     R6_2.4.0       tools_3.2.1    RCurl_1.95-4.8 digest_0.6.10  bitops_1.0-6

Comment: I cannot update because of the Mac version (10.8.5, Lion)

Comment: You will need the correct versions of Xcode and dplyr. Also unpack the package and use the DESCRIPTION file to find the correct versions of dependencies.

Comment: how do I do that? Thanks!